# Time complexity of nested for loops vs loop in a sequence

Tags: time-complexity

I believe this will be faster:
//pseudo code

```
for()
{}
for()
{}
for()
{}
```

than this:

```
for()
{
for()
{
for()
{
}
}
}
```

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. 
The first one has a complexity of O(n) while the second stand at O(n3) [n cube].